# Print all parameter name of a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, c#, data-structures

I have a javascript file in which I have defined a custom function which take some input object and perform some action.
This file is called from many files.
Now I want to priint all the params name used in this function.

May be I need to read whole file as a string and print the desired output

```
 function customFunction(param){
       if(param.isOK == yes){}
       if(param.hasMenu == no){}
       ..
       ..
       ..
       if(param.cancelText == "cancel"){}

    }
```

I want to write a program which reads this file and output all the params name.
e.g.

**isOK |  hasMenu |  ......  | CancelText ..**

Comment: param is object or string??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace _32666940
{

    class Program
    {
        public static String str = "function customFunction(param){ " +
            "if(param.isOK == yes){}" +
            "if(param.hasMenu == no){}" +
            "if(param.cancelText == \"cancel\"){}" +    // I had to add \ before "
            "if(param[  'isOK'  ] == yes){}" +
            "if(param[\"isOK\"] == yes){}" +
            "}";
        static void Main()
        {
            //@"param\.[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"param\.[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
            Match match = regex.Match(str);
            while (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }

            regex = new Regex(@"\bparam\[\s*(['""])(.+?)\1\s*]");
            match = regex.Match(str);
            while (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** updated the code to match `param['some-key']`

**Edit** updated the code to match `param["some-key"]`

Comment: This will not get properties which are accessed using array notation: e.g. param['this-is-another-property']

Comment: This solve my one problem. Can you please provide me the regex for situation like param['this-is-another-property']

Comment: I've updated the code again. The code is now working in all cases. You can also have a glance here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676695/regular-expression-to-detect-double-quoted-javascript-object-properties-with-bra/32676719?noredirect=1#32676719

Answer (score 0):

If param is object, then you can use jQuery `each()` method.
`$.each()` is an object iterator utility.

You can loop through this object using each() method as following

```
$.each( param, function( key, value ) {
     console.log(value);
    //Add your logic as per requirement
});
```

It will print all the values(in console) available in the param object.

Ref: [jQuery each()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/)

Comment: In this way I need to pass all the param's during function call.. This is the main issue .. I have to calculate  the number of parameter that I am supporting in this function .. It is around 1000 . I can not pass all the params at a time.. Different combinations of param are passed from different file