# Regular expression to detect double quoted javascript object properties with brackets

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

There are three ways to access JavaScript Object property.

1. `someObject.propertyName`
2. `someObject['propertyName'] // with single quote '`
3. `someObject["propertyName"] // with double quote "`

Spaces between the brackets, i.e., `someObject[   'propertyName'   ]` or `someObject[   "propertyName"   ]`, are allowed.

To detect all properties of the object `someObject` within a text file, I wrote the following regexes.

1. `Regex regex = new Regex(@"someObject\.[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*");` to detect properties of the form `someObject.propertyName`.
2. `regex = new Regex(@"someObject\[[ ]*'[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*'[ ]*\]");` to detect properties of the form `someObject['propertyName']`.

But I couldn't write regular expression for the properties of the form `someObject["propertyName"]`. Whenever I try to write `"` or `\"` within a regular expression visual studio gives error.

I found some regular expression in the internet to detect double quoted text. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024073/regex-c-sharp-extract-text-within-double-quotes). But I couldn't add `\[` and `\]` in the regex, visual studio gives error.

How the properties of the form `someObject["propertyName"]` can be detected?

I'm using C# `System.Text.RegularExpressions` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I couldn't write regular expression for the properties of the form `someObject["propertyName"]`:

You can use this regex:

```
\bsomeObject\[\s*(['"])(.+?)\1\s*\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lO3hT1/2)

Or to match any object:

```
\b\w+\[\s*(['"])(.+?)\1\s*\]
```

In `C#`,  regex would be like

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\bsomeObject\[\s*(['""])(.+?)\1\s*]");
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b      # word boundary
\w+     # match any word
\[      # match opening [
\s*     # match 0 or more whitespaces
(['"])  # match ' or " and capture it in group #1
(.+?)   # match 0 or more any characters
\1      # back reference to group #1 i.e. match closing ' or "
\s*     # match 0 or more whitespaces
\]      # match closing ]
```

Comment: When I try to write these regex in visual studio, it gives error. [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7bo0bS). Visual Studio doesn't compile it.

Comment: Try: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"\bsomeObject\[\s*(['""])(.+?)\1\s*]");`

Comment: Thanks :D. I'll be very pleased, if you explain it to me. Why visual studio gave error? and where can I get a proper documentation. I searched for it since last night and couldn't solve it.

Comment: [Se this MSDN Q&A](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ef910bd-2431-4229-95dc-a5c6fe7a6af6/including-quotes-in-a-c-regex-pattern?forum=csharplanguage)